# Range Slider issue in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, rangeslider

I've used the Xamarin Range Slider component for a two way slider in my app but it is raising a random exception "Value cannot be null.Parameter name: image". But the range slider have no such image parameter or property. And I haven't found any work around yet. Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

## Update 1:

Here's my code snippet where I've used this Range Slider to represent budget range in my app. Do have a look and tell me if I'm doing something wrong:

```
rangeSlider = new RangeSliderView {
                Frame = new CGRect (lblMinValue.Frame.X, lblMinValue.Frame.Bottom, btnBudgetPlan.Frame.Width, 15),
                AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth,
                TintColor = UIColor.Green,


            };
        
            rangeSlider.MinValue = 0f;
            minBudget = rangeSlider.MinValue.ToString ();

        

            //if (maxRange == null && budgetList != null)
            rangeSlider.MaxValue = Convert.ToInt32 (maxRange, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            maxBudget = maxRange;

            rangeSlider.LeftValueChanged += value => {
                doneButtonDidPressed ();
                var intValue = (int)value;
                lblMinValue.Text = intValue.ToString ();
                minBudget = intValue.ToString ();
            };

            rangeSlider.RightValueChanged += value => {
                doneButtonDidPressed ();
                var intValue = (int)value;
                lblMaxValue.Text = intValue.ToString ();
                maxBudget = intValue.ToString ();
            };

            viewBudget.AddSubviews (btnBudgetPlan, tableBudgetPlan, lblMinValue, lblMaxValue, rangeSlider);
```

Comment: Please post code snippets and stacktrace.

Comment: Hi @Nfear..thanks for reply. It's a random crash and occurs randomly not always and I've posted my code snippet in my post . Check the code in Update 1 of my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue in xamarin forms. Updating the packages helped me.